# What is the point of the built-in functions isequal, isnotequal, isgreater, etc.?

Tags: opencl

In OpenCL, what is the point of the built-in functions isequal, isnotequal, isgreater, etc.? Why not ==, !=, >, etc.? Are the semantics different? Do the operators have limitations that the functions do not? The spec is not clear about this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be used with vector types, e.g. `float3`.

Comment: Ah, so the operators work with vector integers, but not vector floats.  Thanks for the answer.